# Docker Image file details

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is a Docker Image file equivalent to a manifest file which contains pointers to what is present inside the Docker Image - aka the different layers - the amalgamation of which is the Docker Image

OR

Is a docker image file a monolithic image housing all the different layers within it and not necessarily pointing to different sub layers?

Comment: and is documented here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Comment: @DanLowe that is an old spec. There were big change in [v1.1 (Docker 1.10)](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/image/spec/v1.1.md) and was update to [v1.2 (Docker 1.12)](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/image/spec/v1.2.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Docker image](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/image/spec/v1.2.md) is essentially a JSON manifest that includes, among other things, references to file system layers by a SHA256 content checksum.

A layer is a read only set of filesystem changes, that when combined with the other layers produces the file system for your image.

Layers can be shared between images

#### Inspecting an Image

The `RootFS` property of `docker inspect <image>` lists the layers for an image

```
→ docker inspect openjdk:8-jre-alpine
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:d85b17c6762eb3455c7b7ff1930bdde8c911137fe8c7f3c0b5988c66149dc27b",
        "RepoTags": [
            "openjdk:8-jre-alpine"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "openjdk@sha256:48ac96e309a748f5778db26be7e45ca0e35931ef58e9b271fe36767a55411728"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2016-12-27T18:38:49.797530681Z",
        "Container": "de5e277bf3e5ac747933bbb8e703382b240fdcdaef9d927faa4e02c1f0cbc35e",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "26ba10d264c2",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u111",
                "JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.111.14-r0"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "set -x \t&& apk add --no-cache \t\topenjdk8-jre=\"$JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION\" \t&& [ \"$JAVA_HOME\" = \"$(docker-java-home)\" ]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:7bf1d56e53b8a99662fc8314d3860b68f30798646ca0265aeeaa1275f679d314",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "1.12.3",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "26ba10d264c2",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u111",
                "JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.111.14-r0"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:7bf1d56e53b8a99662fc8314d3860b68f30798646ca0265aeeaa1275f679d314",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 107853459,
        "VirtualSize": 107853459,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "overlay2",
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fccc5a703d4022f0fb561a3d0bc6c75da8a99aa1b3291f6be92bf8908e8d5add/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/96ba8cd8b7b44ef284070bd4b98d912fd0bd2b9d6a0d906e661db901408ef38e/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/890f1dbb6c802344c58a32e0ee6d2b49dea74418963ab10a0b649ddc50da6127/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/890f1dbb6c802344c58a32e0ee6d2b49dea74418963ab10a0b649ddc50da6127/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/890f1dbb6c802344c58a32e0ee6d2b49dea74418963ab10a0b649ddc50da6127/work"
            }
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:7cbcbac42c44c6c38559e5df3a494f44987333c8023a40fec48df2fce1fc146b",
                "sha256:da07d9b32b0090fa42690c204d7b49925b5e65ea770893d02c01ab00d61ff920",
                "sha256:6f7515f190962a84c9837ad7adb1e684d79fa0d798a57a99fbe090cc0f97f39c"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

You can see from the `docker history` of the image, there were three commands in the Dockerfile that modified the file system. All other commands contribute to the metadata associated with the image (Use `--no-trunc` to get the full output)

```
→ docker history openjdk:8-jre-alpine
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
d85b17c6762e        2 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -x  && apk add --no-cache  ...   103 MB              
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION...   0 B                 
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_VERSION=8u111       0 B                 
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbi...   0 B                 
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/...   0 B                 
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c {   echo '#!/bin/sh';   echo 's...   87 B                
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0 B                 
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:eeed5f514a35d18...   4.8 MB
```